# Change messages display duration

Tags: statusline, error

Is there a way to make Vim's messages stay longer on the screen?

Messages and error messages are currently shown for a very short time; for about half-second, if not mistaken.

Comment: look that answer https://superuser.com/questions/1065125/how-to-control-vim-message-display-time

Comment: Which messages are shown for a very short time? Messages shouldn't get auto-hidden, but they sometimes do due to the effect of some key mappings or autocommands.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
:messages
```

to review the messages.

Not exactly an answer to the question though.